# WaveShare Touchscreen RPI4 B kivy Input are doubled

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, spi, touchscreen, input-device

I am on a projet for school using kivy on Rasp pi 4 Model B and I am using a WaveShare 7" Touchscreen.

Normal setup (Touchscreen plug on RPI) : When i use my mouse (pluged to the RPI), function get call one time but when i use touchscreen, funtion get call twice.

On my PC (TouchScreen plug on my pc and code running on my pc) :  That works normaly when i use Touchscreen or my mouse (one call by touch).

I have already try some modification on my kivy config.ini but nothing works.

My python code :

```
class WindowStart(Screen):

compteur = 0


def on_enter(self):
    self.pushButton = False
    
    # while(GPIO.input(21) == 1 and self.compteur < SCAN_TIMING_MAX):
    #     self.compteur = 1 + self.compteur
    #     time.sleep(0.1)
    # if(GPIO.input(21) == 0):
    #     App.get_running_app().root.current = 'adminInscriptionChoice'

def stopAdminButton(self):

    
    self.readAdminButton = False
    print('Function called')
    App.get_running_app().root.current = 'authentification'

class FenetreManager(ScreenManager):
     pass

kv = Builder.load_file("monkv.kv")

class MonApplicationPrincipale(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (223/255,223/255,223/255,1)
        return kv    

if __name__=="__main__":
MonApplicationPrincipale().run()
```

my .kv

```
<WindowStart>:
name: "start"
BoxLayout:

    canvas :
        Rectangle:
            source:'helmo.jfif'
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos   
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing:
        20
    padding:
        20
    size:
        root.width, root.height
    Label:
        id : txtConfig
        text:"Appuyer pour commencer"
    RoundedButton:
        id : Btn
        text:"Commencer"
        #disabled:True
        on_release:
            root.stopAdminButton()
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        pos_hint:
            {'center_x':0.5}
        size_hint:
            (0.9,0.9)
```

Input from config.txt of kivy:

```
[input]
;%(name)s = probesysfs
 mouse = mouse
 mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
 hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

My log :

```
/home/smartlocker/Raspberry/Smart-Locker.py:4: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
import imp
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_23-12-05_2.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist- 
packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer 
ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'2.1 Mesa 20.3.5'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Broadcom'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'V3D 4.2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.20'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard allowed, single mode, docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2

[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: xclip
[INFO   ] [CutBuffer   ] cut buffer support enabled
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event3
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event3>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event3> range position X is 0 - 4096
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event3> range position Y is 0 - 4096
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event3> range touch major is 0 - 4096
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event3> range touch minor is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event3> range pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event3> axes inversion: X is 0, Y is 0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event3> rotation set to 0
```

My xinput :

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    vc4-hdmi-0                                  id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    vc4-hdmi-1                                  id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    WaveShare WS170120                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    vc4-hdmi-0                                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    vc4-hdmi-1                                  id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    CHICONY USB Keyboard                        id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

If someone have an idea. I can try it.

Comment: Maybe the problem can from the Screen Class, cause when I moved the window i can continue to click on the button in his previous place on the Screen. But that call him once time